# List of all interfaces in my mac laptop

Tags: macos

Below is the machine:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin whatever 18.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Sun Dec  1 18:59:03 PST 2019; root:xnu-4903.278.19~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
$
```

---

In ubuntu, `ip addr` or `ip a` gives list of all interfaces.

What is the similar command in mac?

Comment: I think this is a better question for [apple.se]

Comment: Does `netstat -i` work on a Mac?

Comment: @roaima: Yes it does.

Answer (score 1):

`ifconfig` is probably the tool you're looking for.

You can also use:

```
networksetup -listallhardwareports
```

Although this won't give as much detail

Comment: `ifconfig all` ?

Comment: @overexchange: Nope just `ifconfig` with no arguments

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of the interfaces you can use `netstat -i`